# How to move sprite from right to left of screen using CGPathAddArc

Tags: path, automatic-ref-counting, sprite

my sprite position is (screenWidth, screenHeigh/2). i have tried a lot of code which using CGPathAddArc to move sprite from right to left but not success. apple document is so hard to understand. so i post here with a hope someone can help me.
this is one of the code i had used.

```
if (iPad) {
        CGPathAddArc(thePath, NULL, 384.0f , 768, 384.0f , 0.f, -M_PI*3/2, NO);
}
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction followPath:thePath asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:(5.0f/200.0f)*(iPad ? 384.0f :200.f)];
```

many thank in advance

Comment: Please check my answer - alternatively I can upload to github too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a blank SpriteKit project, this slightly modified default code for GameScene.m will make the spaceship fly through from right to left following a half-circle path.

Pls comment if you need further clarification!

Key difference from your code snippet that for `[SKAction followPath...]` the `asOffset` parameter is NO, and the `orientToPath` is YES.

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

    myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 65;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:myLabel];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

        sprite.xScale = 0.5;
        sprite.yScale = 0.5;
        sprite.position = location;

        // HERE COMES THE MODIFICATION
        CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(thePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2 , 200, self.frame.size.width/2 , 0.f, -M_PI, NO);
        SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction followPath:thePath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5.0];
        [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveAction]];
        // HERE ENDS THE MODIFICATION

        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Hope this helps!